# How to make the ip of my computer public so that devices outside the same network can access webservice in that particular ip

Tags: networking

i have an android application using webservice  which is working fine from inside a network. i mean, if both mobile and computer are connected to the same network, i can run the app perfectly, but if i change network of any one of it to another network then, 'cannot establish connection to server' error is shown. 
What i want is to get an ip from which i can acess the app from any network

this is how my connection code in the android application looks like

```
mWebview .loadUrl("http://192.193.194.195/Application/startpage.php");
```

please give me step by step instructions, i searched for it a lot, but i couldnt find a good answer for my level 0 networking knowledge :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to host the server on a [public IP address](http://support.slingbox.com/get/KB-2000143.html) where every network can see the server.

Answer (score -2):

Then you have to use the external/internet ip addres of your router. Find out with http://whatismyip.com Then on your router forward port 80 to your pc with ip 192.193.194.195.